# Closing tags in a Digitally signed document

Tags: c#, digital-signature

I followed the example from microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-sign-xml-documents-with-digital-signatures

And I get a signature.

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
        <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>e7jQRU4xmLaQmWVO9pVovhWSeGU=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>gAuVoU7bBgzJCD7VZku1Gvju4h/R4mQZGEXK5BoIAKbmYJqeWCYAdvb07gVwaFOc6DeQPmV3lS0BGE4wOZkNqvLqN2BhIM98hYSwd1KZgBDzkrNs6GoLmDLiJVwC+rq2IYOKfQumk3sD7V7KBZ/92/dbXPfPUOLEQRmF9tkJZBA=</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
```

But it is not exactly the format i need. I need to send Digital Signatures like these :

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod>
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod>
        <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
            <DigestValue>e7jQRU4xmLaQmWVO9pVovhWSeGU=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>gAuVoU7bBgzJCD7VZku1Gvju4h/R4mQZGEXK5BoIAKbmYJqeWCYAdvb07gVwaFOc6DeQPmV3lS0BGE4wOZkNqvLqN2BhIM98hYSwd1KZgBDzkrNs6GoLmDLiJVwC+rq2IYOKfQumk3sD7V7KBZ/92/dbXPfPUOLEQRmF9tkJZBA=</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
```

Notice the closing tags here. Is there a way I can instruct the xmlDigitalSignature component to spit out the xml i need ?

Comment: The two format are equivalent.  Xml specification says that the name is not required in the closing tag. So <name>abc</name>  and <name>abc</> are equivalent

Comment: I am sorry i did not explain the problem well enough...... The digest  value is correct but the party that is sending (and receiving) the digital signature, uses the close tags as well to calculate the signvalue :-( ....... If I create a digital signature for them, they cannot validate it. For now I have to do an ugly string replace and then recalculate the signvalue and then use that. I was wondering if i could instruct .Net to use full open and close tags.

Comment: I'm confused.  The signature is a CRC of the data and tags.  To as long as the CRC and the data and tags are the same is shouldn't matter  If I CRC <root></root> and add the CRC "ABC" then the signature will validate.  Then I do a CRC of <root></> and get CRC "DEF" the signature and CRC will again be consistent and validate.  It should not make any difference in the validation if you include or do not include the closing tags as long as the signature is consistent with the data.

Comment: Oh I am sorry again, the CRC is different (although not in the example above because I editted that manually). So The one who reads my signature is calculating the SignatureValue again  inluding "complete" closing tags, and then compares the signvalue. Which is different because .Net creates the digsig based on "normal" closing tags. So back to my oiriginal question. Is there a way to instruct the .Net signing component to create a signature with the start tag and a corresponding end tag. So in need the signvalue to be calculated over <some></some> instead over <some />

Comment: Are you sure net creates CRC always with closing tags or does it really just do a CRC on the on the XML string?  As long as the XML string and the CRC were using same string it shouldn't make a difference.